# Get count between day time intervals

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have data which has start_time and end_time as columns. For now I am trying out a sample data with this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'start_time': ["2023-05-03 10:30:00", "2023-05-03 10:02:00", "2023-05-03 10:10:00", "2023-05-03 11:00:00", "2023-05-03 11:05:00"], 'end_time': ["2023-05-03 10:35:00", "2023-05-03 10:20:00", "2023-05-03 10:32:00", "2023-05-03 11:10:00", "2023-05-03 11:09:00"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df["start_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start_time"])
df["end_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["end_time"])
```

this gives me something like this:

[image: start_end time table]

I want to create another data frame which grabs the min time and max time out of the above table and create a time interval of 30 mins and also get me a count of rows which fall at the time mark. The table for now looks like this:

[image: 30 mins interval count]

So for example, in the above table, Along with that time 2023-05-03 10:02:00 I also need how many rows were active at that time mark from start_end time table. So something like this:

time                                         count

2023-05-03 10:02:00                    1             (since only 1 process is active at this time)

2023-05-03 10:32:00                   3             (at 10:32 we have 3 active processes)

2023-05-03 11:02:00                  1

I was able to achieve to get the 30 mins range with this:

```
idx = pd.date_range(df["start_time"].min(), df["end_time"].max(), freq="30T").to_frame(index=False, name='time')
```

for count I have been trying to use double for loop to get the count between 2 date ranges.

```
count = 0
for ind, row in idx.iterrows():
  for ind1, row1 in df.iterrows():
    if(row["time"] >= row1["start_time"] and row["time"] <= row1["end_time"]):
      print("Entering here...")
      count += 1
```

I guess that is too expensive and slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) on the `min`/`max` of the stacked data to get your `idx`, then a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
idx = pd.date_range(*df.stack().agg(['min', 'max']), freq='30min')

(pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values(by='start_time'), pd.Series(idx, name='time'),
               left_on='start_time', right_on='time', direction='forward'
              )
   .query('time <= end_time')
   ['time'].value_counts().reindex(idx)
)
```

Output:

```
2023-05-03 10:02:00    1
2023-05-03 10:32:00    2
2023-05-03 11:02:00    1
Freq: 30T, Name: time, dtype: int64
```

Comment: `merge_asof` cannot guarantee the correct solution because each row can be counted at most one. This is not true if some events are long enough, e.g. more than 1 hour.

Comment: @Quang doesn't seem to be the case here. If it was, then you could count how many periods the `start-end` spans and propagate the count to the following bins.

Comment: Or perform a double `merge_asof` to get the min/max matching time, then compute the number of periods. OP should update the question and example if this is a possible behavior and I'll try to update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your data. If the table and the time period are relatively small, you can perform a cross merge and query:

```
(df.merge(idx, how='cross').query('start_time <= time <= end_time')
   .groupby('time').size()
)
```

Output:

```
2023-05-03 10:02:00    1
2023-05-03 10:32:00    2
2023-05-03 11:02:00    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using iterrows for loops on pandas unless you **realllly** need it. You can easily use an apply function which has better performance. As an example:

```
idx["count"] = idx.apply(lambda x: ((df.start_time <= x.time) & (df.end_time >= x.time)).sum(), axis=1)
```

Outpu of given code:

```
                 time  count
0 2023-05-03 10:02:00      1
1 2023-05-03 10:32:00      2
2 2023-05-03 11:02:00      1
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an inequality join - [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join) covers this:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.conditional_join(
    idx, 
    ('start_time', 'time', '<='), 
    ('end_time', 'time', '>='))
.groupby('time')
.size()
)
time
2023-05-03 10:02:00    1
2023-05-03 10:32:00    2
2023-05-03 11:02:00    1
dtype: int64
```